# create a sublist from a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have a python list as follows:

```
list_ = [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7, 100]
```

I want to create another list such as below; (Note that the last `100` is not included!!)

```
new_list = [[-100], [-100, 1], [-100, 1, 3], [-100, 1, 3, 5], [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

I tried as follows:

```
new_list = []

for i in list_:
    new_list.append(list([i]))
```

It generates `[[-100], [1], [3], [5], [7], [100]]`, which is not the one I want.

Comment: `new_list = [lst[:i] for i in range(1, len(lst))]`

Answer (score 3):

Is this want you want?

```
l = [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7, 100]
print([l[:i+1] for i in range(0, len(l) - 1)])
```

Output:

```
[[-100], [-100, 1], [-100, 1, 3], [-100, 1, 3, 5], [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

Or even simpler:

```
print([l[:i] for i in range(1, len(l))])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you meant:

```
list_ = [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7, 100]

new_list = []

for i in range(1, len(list_)):
    new_list.append(list_[:i])

print(new_list)
# outputs [[-100], [-100, 1], [-100, 1, 3], [-100, 1, 3, 5], [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

In each iteration, we take the list [slice](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) up to index `i`, starting at index 0 up until `len(list_) - 1`, using [`range`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) to generate the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to do here is work with list slices like so:

```
new_list = []

for i in range(1,len(list_)):
    new_list.append(list_[:i])
```

printing the list produced by this loop yields:

```
[[-100], [-100, 1], [-100, 1, 3], [-100, 1, 3, 5], [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

For more details on how list slicing works, see the slicing section in the informal introduction to Python here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

What about a [recursive function](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/)?

```
list_ = [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7, 100]
matrix_ = []


def matrix(lst):
    if not lst:
        return
    length = len(lst)-1
    if length:
        matrix_.append(lst[:length])
        matrix(lst[:length])

x = matrix(list_)
print(matrix_)
```

### output

```
[[-100, 1, 3, 5, 7], [-100, 1, 3, 5], [-100, 1, 3], [-100, 1], [-100]]
```

Then reverse it if you want:

```
matrix_.reverse()
print(matrix_)
# [[-100], [-100, 1], [-100, 1, 3], [-100, 1, 3, 5], [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

### Additional

**1. Using a While loop**

```
list_ = [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7, 100]


def matrix(lst):

    matrix_ = []
    count = 0
    prev = []
    while count < len(lst)-1:
        prev.append(lst[count])
        matrix_.append(prev.copy())
        count += 1
    return matrix_


x = matrix(list_)
print(x)
# [[-100], [-100, 1], [-100, 1, 3], [-100, 1, 3, 5], [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

**2. Using [Generator Function](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)**

```
list_ = [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7, 100]


def matrix(lst):
    matrix_ = []
    count = 0
    prev = []
    while count < len(lst)-1:
        prev.append(lst[count])
        matrix_.append(prev.copy())
        count += 1
    yield matrix_


x = list(matrix(list_))
print(x[0])
# [[-100], [-100, 1], [-100, 1, 3], [-100, 1, 3, 5], [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

**3. [Enumerate](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/)**

```
list_ = [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7, 100]


def matrix(lst):
    result = []
    for idx, _ in enumerate(lst):
        if idx:
            list_block = lst[:idx]
            result.append(list_block)
    return result

x = matrix(list_)
print(x)
# [[-100], [-100, 1], [-100, 1, 3], [-100, 1, 3, 5], [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

**4. [range function](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range)**

```
list_ = [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7, 100]


def matrix(lst):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if i:
            list_block = lst[:i]
            result.append(list_block)
    return result

x = matrix(list_)
print(x)
# [[-100], [-100, 1], [-100, 1, 3], [-100, 1, 3, 5], [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

**5. Using itertools [takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) just for fun**

```
from itertools import takewhile

list_ = [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7, 100]


def make_list(item):

    matrix = []
    for i in range(1, len(item)):
        wanted_items = list(takewhile(lambda x: x != item[-i], item))
        matrix.append(wanted_items)
    matrix.reverse()
    return matrix

result = make_list(list_)
print(result)
# [[-100], [-100, 1], [-100, 1, 3], [-100, 1, 3, 5], [-100, 1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
lst=[-100,1,3,5,7,100]
new_list = []

for i in range(len(lst):
    new_list.append(lst[:i])
```

Comment: Aside from the missing parenthesis, this solution is incorrect.

Comment: I didn't execute the code, wanted to post the approach to `lst[:i]` as the solution. But that's on me, should have executed it.